# JSF - Two Questions about actions on UIComponent

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, action, facelets

So, let me show us my troubles :)

**1 - When i click on a commandbutton**

```
<h:commandButton value="Somethings">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.method}" value="some" />
    <f:ajax render="rendering"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

I dont do any *action* to the `commandButton`. Just i fire the ajax call. If i add an action on the button (like `action="bean.myAction`) it will be executedat the 5° phase of the JSF lifecycle (allright, only if i write event="action" in the f:ajax, but thats as default). Right? But the f:ajax is fired by cliccing on the button as default? Because for a ListBox for example, it's fired only if i write event="change" (the same, i shouldnt write it, because is as default).

**2 - When i click on image**

```
<h:graphicImage value="img/img.png" alt="img">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.method}" value="some" />
    <f:ajax event="onclick" render="rendering"/>
</h:graphicImage>
```

This doesnt work. Why?

As usual, thanks for the help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **1 - When i click on a commandbutton**
>
> I dont do any action to the commandButton. Just i fire the ajax call. If i add an action on the button (like action="bean.myAction) it will be executedat the 5° phase of the JSF lifecycle

The [`f:setPropertyActionListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/setPropertyActionListener.html) will be executed in the 5th phase as well.

> (allright, only if i write event="action" in the f:ajax, but thats as default). Right? But the f:ajax is fired by cliccing on the button as default? Because for a ListBox for example, it's fired only if i write event="change" (the same, i shouldnt write it, because is as default).

The [`f:ajax`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html) just changes the behaviour from a synchronous submit to asynchronous (partial) submit. It does that by generating some additional JavaScript code to the desired event attribute of the parent component (e.g. `onclick`, `onchange`, etc, look in generated HTML output in webbrowser). It doesn't change anything in the JSF lifecycle. Only the rendered response will be a partial response which is exactly the part which is to be updated in the component(s) with ID as definied in `render` attribute.

---

> **2 - When i click on image**
>
> This doesnt work. Why?

Because the [`h:graphicImage`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/graphicImage.html) does not support `f:setPropertyActionListener` at all. It only works in [`UICommand`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UICommand.html) components.

You want to wrap it in a `h:commandLink` instead.

```
<h:commandLink>
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.method}" value="some" />
    <f:ajax event="action" render="rendering"/>
    <h:graphicImage value="img/img.png" alt="img"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

*(and if necessary style the border/underline caused by generated `<a>` element away with CSS)*

Comment: for the first question : OK. But what I still dont understand is this : for a ListBox, the `f:ajax` is called when che ListBox change for example. (`event="change"`). But for the button? How say that when you press it you need to execute the code on it? Its the default behaviour i think, or i forgot somethings?

Comment: The default `f:ajax` event for `UICommand` (actually, `ActionSource`) components is `click`. See also the description of the `event` attribute in the `f:ajax` PDL document which I linked in my answer (all those blueish code parts in my answer are actually links to the official reference documentation).

Comment: Uhm. So if i write my own `action="bean.myFunction"` on `commandButton` and i use `f:ajax event="click"` the action won't be executed?

Comment: It will be executed. The `f:ajax` only changes it from synchronous (normal/full) submit to an asynchronous (ajaxical/partial) submit. Leaving JSF outside the question, do you understand anyway what the whole point of Ajax is?

Comment: So : `f:ajax event="action"` what mean? :)

Comment: On `UICommand` components, it has the same meaning/effect as `click`. Edit: actually, I think I see your confusion, it's called `action` in the docs. But actually, the `action` is kind of alias for `click`. Sorry for causing some confusion.

Comment: ah OK! :) Regard second point, the button will be displayed only if i write `<f:ajax render=":render"/>`. With `<f:ajax event="onclick" render=":render"/>` the code fails!

Comment: The `onclick` is not a valid event name. You need `click`. The `onclick` is a typical HTML element attribute name.

Comment: Ok. I pasted from your suggestion :) Thanks.. **AGAIN**!!

Comment: To all readers: I have to rectify myself, the default `event` for `UICommand` components is `action`, not `click`. JSF interprets both differently. It's definitely not an alias.