# Div updating with image dynamically..... JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jstl

How to replace an image in DIV dynamically on click of some other div image as shown in image.
Requirement is like that : 
on click of "DIV1" root should be updated with 1.. on click of "Div2" root should be updated with 2 like that.  All div having image loading from some URL and Root is a bigger div.
[image]

please reply ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<div>
   <h:graphicImage id="root" value="#{managedBean.rootImage}" alt="image"/>
</div>

<div>
   <h:commandLink>
     <h:graphicImage value="images/image1.png" alt="image1"/>
     <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{managedBean.rootImage}" value="images/image1.png" />
     <f:ajax event="action" render="root"/>  
   </h:commandLink>
</div>
```

And in your ManagedBean create setter/getters like this:

```
public class ManagedBean{
    public String rootImage;
    public void setRootImage(String image) {
      this.rootImage= image;
    }
    public String getRootImage() {
      return rootImage;
    }
}
```

Reference: [JSF - Two Questions about actions on UIComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326705/jsf-two-questions-about-actions-on-uicomponent)

Comment: <f:ajax> is not a valid syntax for jsf what i am using  any alternative for this ... which will solve my problem

Comment: oh if you are using JSF 1.2 then read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545539/how-do-i-call-a-jsf-action-method-in-jsf-1-2-using-ajax

Comment: <f:ajax> is not a valid syntax for jsf ... it is giving message like this... i am using jsf 2.0

Comment: i am using <%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%> as tag line in my code that is the reason i guess it is giving error ..

Comment: See the documentation for syntax at this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/index.html)

Comment: it worked just i changed ... .jsp to .xhtml in name extension file name

Comment: May be you should create a new question and post your XHTML file for us to look at.